# Xming Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 Linux Subsystem

Tags: linux, windows-10, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

What I am trying to do is basically run Visual Studio Code on the Linux subsystem of a Windows 10 Anniversary Update machine. I have installed the code.xxx.deb package using gdebi and solved the few requirements missing. I have Xming installed on Windows, which works (I've tried it with xeyes and firefox). However, that doesn't seem to work when I run `DISPLAY=:0 code`. The terminal becomes available again without any error message. By running `DISPLAY=:0 code --verbose`, I get the following:

```
[6952:0213/151841:FATAL:render_sandbox_host_linux.cc(40)] Check failed: 0 == shutdown(renderer_socket_, SHUT_RD). shutdown: Invalid argument
#0 0x000001e52dce <unknown>
#1 0x000001e68acb <unknown>
#2 0x000001e6908d <unknown>
#3 0x00000292b5e2 <unknown>
#4 0x0000026f44b5 <unknown>
#5 0x0000026fa81f <unknown>
#6 0x0000026f3c46 <unknown>
#7 0x00000121ccf7 <unknown>
#8 0x00000121b7d0 <unknown>
#9 0x000003473ea3 main
#10 0x7f4d58c81f45 __libc_start_main
#11 0x000000574509 <unknown>
```

I am not really sure how to deal with this. It must be something specific to this package but I can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: the reason I'm trying to do this is to use the Visual Studio Code GUI debugger as I am compiling under the Ubuntu subsystem only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue, see [#1587](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1587) on the Bash On Windows issue tracker, which has the exact same error message.

It might already work with one of the more recent preview builds of Windows:

> Electron definitely is known to be broken on 14393. Supposedly people have gotten vscode working on 15002, and that runs in electron [...]

[Build 15002 was released to the "fast ring" on January 9, 2017.](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/01/09/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-15002-pc/)