# visual studio code does not launch on windows 10 subsystem for linux (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-10, xming

I am on windows 10 and have installed Linux (Ubuntu) directly from the store  [using the guidelines given here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)
I also have Xming and have set DISPLAY=:0 in my bashrc file.
Programs such as Firefox and PyCharm run just fine but VSCode does not run.
It's not the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208199/xming-visual-studio-code-on-windows-10-linux-subsystem)and the produced error messages seem different. 
running it with --verbose option I got below:

```
Me@DESKTOP-1:/mnt/e/ubuntu-stored/repoitories/pawlib$ code .
Me@DESKTOP-1:/mnt/e/ubuntu-stored/repoitories/pawlib$ which code
/usr/bin/code
Me@DESKTOP-1:/mnt/e/ubuntu-stored/repoitories/pawlib$ code --verbose
[3773:0916/193522.695084:ERROR:bus.cc(395)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
[main 7:35:23 PM] Starting VS Code
[main 7:35:23 PM] from: /usr/share/code/resources/app
[main 7:35:23 PM] args: { _: [],
  help: false,
  h: false,
  version: false,
  v: false,
  wait: false,
  w: false,
  diff: false,
  d: false,
  add: false,
  a: false,
  goto: false,
  g: false,
  'new-window': false,
  n: false,
  'unity-launch': false,
  'reuse-window': false,
  r: false,
  'open-url': false,
  performance: false,
  p: false,
  'prof-startup': false,
  verbose: true,
  logExtensionHostCommunication: false,
  'disable-extensions': false,
  disableExtensions: false,
  'list-extensions': false,
  'show-versions': false,
  nolazy: false,
  issue: false,
  'skip-getting-started': false,
  'skip-release-notes': false,
  'sticky-quickopen': false,
  'disable-restore-windows': false,
  'disable-telemetry': false,
  'disable-updates': false,
  'disable-crash-reporter': false,
  'skip-add-to-recently-opened': false,
  status: false,
  s: false,
  'file-write': false,
  'file-chmod': false,
  'driver-verbose': false }
[main 7:35:23 PM] Resolving machine identifier...
[main 7:35:23 PM] Resolved machine identifier: d4398814e404b0f7472543859e2fed861c7a29fc750e4c131eab633c4e5a44b8
[main 7:35:23 PM] update#setState idle
[main 7:35:23 PM] windowsManager#open
[3805:0916/193523.829735:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(413)] GLX 1.3 or later is required.
[3805:0916/193523.829875:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(153)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[3805:0916/193523.848836:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(252)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[3773:0916/193523.869175:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.
[3773:0916/193524.216326:ERROR:browser_main_parts.cc(139)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
```

I installed VScode using below commands:

```
$ sudo apt install curl
$ curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
$ sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install code
```

When I got the launch error, I tried installing the .deb file using "dpkg -i" just to make sure the issue wasn't with the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does not support launching the Linux client via WSL, you can however launch the Windows client via WSL by calling `<VS Code Install>\bin\code.sh`.

Also, while it is possible to launch Linux apps through WSL by installing an X server, it's more of an experimental thing. The focus of WSL is about bringing Linux-based command line tools to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Hah!  Mr. Google to the rescue.
Here is the fix:

```
# make a copy of the relevant library
mkdir ~/lib
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 ~/lib
sed -i 's/BIG-REQUESTS/_IG-REQUESTS/' ~/lib/libxcb.so.1
# set the dynamic loader path to put your library first before executing VS Code
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib code
```

This is from:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but I am launching code from a Linux machine.  Xming handles `xterm`, firefox, etc. but is unhappy with vs code.  You can fix the `glx` issues with

```
$ code --disable-gpu

but I still get:
[main 2:29:54 PM] update#setState idle
[main 2:29:54 PM] windowsManager#open
[42083:0108/142954.536002:ERROR:browser_main_parts.cc(139)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)

So maybe an X-server problem?  Maybe try a different X server?
```